# Is it possible to create a "smart playlist" (YouTube Mix) from a set of keywords (artists names)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Is it possible to create a "smart" (or "automatic", or "mix") playlist on YouTube from a set of keywords?

For instance, I want to play a playlist of automatically selected videos matching the keywords "Pearl Jam", "The Doors" and "Pixies".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, have a look at topic "Automatically add videos to playlists":

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6084053?hl=en

Now any newly uploaded videos that meet this criteria will be automatically added to this playlist.

Comment: Please add essential contents of the link into answer. Link only answers would not be valid if URL get changed.